# How to test if file exists and stop

Tags: import

At the moment I'm using >

```
filename = FileNameJoin[{root = "F:\\somefolderpath", file = "somefile.extention"}];
If[! DirectoryQ[root], 
  Print[Style["Directory '" <> root <> "' does not exist!", {Red, Bold, Large}]]; Quit[]];
If[! FileExistsQ[filename], 
  Print[Style["File '" <> filename <> "' does not exist!", {Red, Bold, Large}]]; Quit[]];
(*Start using 'filename'*)
```

edit: Ended up using

```
SafeFile::usage = "Use instead of Import.";
SafeFile::nodir = "Directory `1` does not exist.";
SafeFile::nofile = "File `1` does not exist.";
SafeFile[filename_,root_:NotebookDirectory[]]:=Module[{
    fullfilename=FileNameJoin[{root,filename}]
},
    If[!TrueQ@DirectoryQ@root,Message[SafeFile::nodir,root];Quit[]];
    If[!TrueQ@FileExistsQ@fullfilename,Message[SafeFile::nofile,filename];Quit[]];
    Import[fullfilename]
]
```

Quitting kernel was actually what I needed.

Comment: Please paste the actual code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: The messages would usually be named `SafeFile::nodir`, and you don't need to define them in your function; they can go right next to the `SafeFile::usage` definition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might consider using Messages instead of `Print`.  You should also consider using `TrueQ` if either `root` or `filename` might not be a string.

```
file::nodir = "Directory `1` does not exist.";
file::nofile = "File `1` does not exist.";

If[! TrueQ @ DirectoryQ @ root, Message[file::nodir, root]; Abort[]];
If[! TrueQ @ FileExistsQ @ filename, Message[file::nofile, filename]; Abort[]];
```

Answer (score 7):

What you are doing seems pretty minimal already; the fact that MMA notation is very verbose is something that cannot be avoided. You could separate the whole check into a separate function and put that into an invisible initialization cell so it is out of the way.

As for not killing the kernel, just use `Abort[]` instead of `Quit[]`.