# How to test if Import was successful?

Tags: import, files-and-directories

I am importing and processing a bunch of files. Sometimes, for whatever reason, some of these files are not successfully imported so I'm looking for a way to `Abort` and `Print` some message containing useful information to debug.

I was looking into adapting [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4216/how-to-test-if-file-exists-and-stop) (specifically [Mr.Wizard♦'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4218/1370)) for my purposes. Is there a way to verify if Import generated any errors?

Comment: How about hashing the file and the thing you imported into *Mathematica*, and comparing the hashes?

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't `Check` something you could use?

Comment: welp, this is embarrassing. Yes, `Check` should do the trick.